# Loaders - spinner icon not appearing inside bootstrap modal

Tags: jquery, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to add the spinner icon like below inside a modal dialog box,

[image]

Jsfiddle is [here](https://jsfiddle.net/6b8g4LL1/23/).

I am using [loaders.css](https://github.com/ConnorAtherton/loaders.css) to get this effect. This works, when i place this code in the index page.

```
<div class="text-center loader-inner line-scale"></div>
```

But it doesn't appear when this icon is placed inside a bootstrap modal box.

Is this to do with, `$('.loader-inner').loaders()` function call mentioned on [loader's](https://github.com/ConnorAtherton/loaders.css) github page.

Since this is an angular app, i am trying to skip the jquery dependency somehow.

Comment: add required js & css to your fiddle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I added the css from the loaders.css and looked at the [demo](https://github.com/ConnorAtherton/loaders.css/blob/master/demo/src/demo.jade) to see how to use the specific loading animation. Simply add five div's inside your .line-scale element.
See updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/aw23bfyv/).

```
<div class="text-center loader-inner line-scale">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
</div>
```

Having said that, I noticed that you're using angular. On the [readme](https://github.com/ConnorAtherton/loaders.css/blob/master/README.md) page of loader.css there is a port for angular that might be helpful.